# using this[ ] operator to call sharedObject AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe-animate

it's a bit difficult to explain about this, I'm working on a slightly complicated game using score system made by me, I use the `[]` operator to call variable names like in this post [Calling a variable given its string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316552/calling-a-variable-given-its-string-name)

the goal is that I can change the SharedObject data as desired, first I create a variable data1, data2 etc...

```
var data1 = 0;
userData.data.Game1Score = data1;

var data2 = 0;
userData.data.Game1Score = data2;

// data3, data4, etc.
```

I create a variable so that I can change the data I want to use

```
var data:string;
```

on button i change data variable

```
// function to the Game
function BtnGame1(event:MouseEvent):void {

    data = "data1";

}

function BtnGame2(event:MouseEvent):void {

    data = "data2";

}
```

so that the variable data becomes :

```
trace(data);
// Output:
// data1
// or data2
```

i only want to have 1 page of score result, i changed data1 and data2 using `[]` operator

```
//Button Function to Page Level
function NextoPageLevel(event:MouseEvent):void {

this[data] = 3 //example if score 3
updateScore(); // function for Update SharedObject Data

}
```

then to update ShareObject I created a function :

```
function updateScore():void {

userData.data.Game1Score = data1;
userData.data.Game2Score = data2;

}
```

and the result is working!, SharedObject data is modified and saved, sorry if there is a mistake in English, I only use a translator, for more details I have a .fla file that can be downloaded here
[SetupScore.fla](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V57kHgDi8iwQfzZX6rM4XzLvhsYegCVx/view)

if I make a lot of level games, there will definitely be a lot of syntax that I make, so I make it simple, but the code doesn't work

```
this["userData.data.Game1Score"];
```

OR

```
var data = "userData.data.Game1Score";
this[data] = 3;
```

I want the flow like this

[my game flow concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFGa1.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

```
this["userData"]["data"]["Game1Score"];
```

However, I think there could be a better system for your case - look up design patterns.